# MATLAB: Improving for-loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop

I need to multiply parts of a column vector with a fixed row vector. I solved this problem using a for-loop. However, I am wondering if the performance can be improved as I have to perform this kind of computation around 50 million times. Here's my code so far:

```
multMat = 1:5;
mat = randi(5,10,1);
windowSize = 5;

vout = nan(10,1);
for r = windowSize : 10
    vout(r) = multMat * mat( (r - windowSize + 1) : r);
end
```

I was thinking about uisng `arrayfun`. However, first I don't know how to adress the cell range (i.e. the previous five cells including the current cell), and second, I am not sure if `arrayfun` will be any faster than using the loop?

Comment: `arrayfun` is just a "loop in disguise", under the hood it's basically just looping through elements anyway. Vectorizing your code is the common way to avoid loops for performance in MATLAB. Also note that since the [new JIT compiler in 2016](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/02/12/run-code-faster-with-the-new-matlab-execution-engine/), loops aren't inherently slow.

Comment: @Wolfie Well, how am I supposed to vectorize that stuff?  Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sliding vector multiplication you're describing is an example of what is known as [convolution](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html). The following produces the same result as the loop in your example:

```
vout = [nan(windowSize-1,1);
        conv(mat,flip(multMat),'valid')];
```

If your output doesn't really need the leading `NaN` values which aren't overwritten in your loop then the `conv` expression is sufficient without concatenating the `NaN` elements to it.

For sufficiently large vectors this is of course not guaranteed to be as fast as you'd like it to be, but MATLAB's built-in convolution implementation is likely to be pretty close to an optimal tool for the job.

Comment: “Pretty close to an optimal tool” indeed. In any case, much, much faster than anything you can write by hand in MATLAB!

Comment: @Will Could you please elaborate a bit on your second line in order to make it more dynamic. That is, how would the last part look like, if I were to change `multMat = 1:7` and `windowSize=numel(multMat)`?

Comment: @Andi I actually overcomplicated my original answer because I misunderstood the difference between the output for `conv` I was seeing and the output of your loop. The answer is now edited. The loop is exactly equivalent to `conv(...,'valid')` except for the `NaN`s at the start of the array, which exist because your loop starts at `r = windowSize`. If you change `windowSize`, the number of leading `NaN`s in the array will change accordingly, just as in your original loop.

Comment: @Will That's a great solution! Thanks.